# Set a different home link in nav menu

Tags: menus, home-url

I've my website with homepage link set to http://www.mysite.com.

I've also many pages with subpages, and in that subpages i've already a link in the content that returns to the top level parent page.

Is it also possible to set this link in the nav menu overwriting my default home link?

Thanks,

Stefano

Answer (score 0):

You can put in Custom links from the wordpress menu dashboard.

Comment: But it won't be always the same link. For example:
PAGE 1 -> SUBPAGE 1 (link to PAGE 1) --> SUBPAGE 2 (link to PAGE 1).

PAGE 2 -> SUBPAGE 1 (link to PAGE 2) etc...

Comment: Then do see the documentation for Menu Walker.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function

Using this you can set your conditions accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You could make it with your theme with the hook `wp_nav_menu_items` :

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpse_104145_custom_home_link', 10, 2);
function wpse_104145_custom_home_link($items, $args) {

if( $args->theme_location == 'primary' )
    global $post;
    if($post->post_parent) {
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->post_parent);
    $homeLink = '<li id="home_link"><a href="' . $permalink . '">'.get_the_title($post->post_parent).'</a></li>';
    return $homeLink . $items;
    } else {
    return $items;
    }
}
```